# How to open a bootstrap modal from another view page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a button in one view page.  modal is in another page. I should get that model open when button is clicked. How to achieve this?
There are mainly two view.

1: addactor(partial view)
2:movies.cshtml(main view)

```html
This is movies.cshtml


<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnactor">Add Actor</button>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
@section scripts{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    debugger 
    $(document).delegate`("#btnactor", "click", function () {
        $("#exampleModalactor").modal("show");
    });
</script>
```

Addactor.cshtml This is the partial view.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalactor" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" id="stylemodel">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBodyDiv1">


                <form id="actorform">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <b>@Html.DisplayName("Name")</b>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.name,new {@class="form-control"})
                            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" />
                            <b>@Html.DisplayName("Sex")</b>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.sex, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "" })
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6">
                            <b> DOB </b>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.dob, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "plot" })
                            <b> C </b>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.bio, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "cast" })
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add actor" />
                    <a href="#" id="btnsave" class="btn btn-success">Update Changes</a>
                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveactor" >Add Actor</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why is it in another view ? Is the modal in `Partial` view ? , Can you add your Main view and Another view to question to help further ?

Comment: @stom yeaa..exactly. modal is in partial view

Comment: Can you add your Main view and Partial view to question to help further ?

Comment: @stom I need to call modal in partial from main view. I have a button in main view

Comment: create separate view file of bootstrap modal and than include wherever you want to use.

Comment: @jaypatel That wont work for me. Updated !!please check it out

Comment: can you please add where you are rendering this partial view of yours because in your movies.cshtml i can not see @await Html.PartialAsync("Addactor.cshtml") assuming your partial view is in shared folder. Is it present in your main layout?

Comment: @piyushsanadhya it is in the shared folder. Can you explain the use of it

Comment: is there any error or something? please elaborate it properly so others can help you out...

Answer (score 0):

Try below code to call your modal.

```
$(document).delegate("#btnactor", "click", function () { 
     $("#exampleModalactor").modal("show");        
});
```

Hope this code useful for your issue :)

Comment: Show your code little more brother. so someone can understand what you need exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing your Main view and `Partial` view , I wrote below answer as an example.

Below Setup should work to show Partial view modal in your Main View.

**Action Methods**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

 return View();
}


public PartialViewResult GetSomeData()
{
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Just to show delay to Get data

   ViewBag.Message = "Example Data from Server"; //Using ViewBag Just for example, use ViewModel Instead

   return PartialView("~/Views/Shared/_ExamplePartial.cshtml");
}
```

**Index View**

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnGetData">
    Get Modal With Partial
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="partialViewContent">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_ExamplePartial View**

```
<h2>Partial View Contents</h2>


 <h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>


<p>Some More Static Content</p>
```

**Script:**

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnGetData').click(function () {


            var requestUrl = '@Url.Action("GetSomeData", "Home")';

            $.get(requestUrl)

            .done(function (responsedata) {

                console.log("success");

                $("#partialViewContent").html(responsedata);

                $('#myModal').modal('show')

            })
            .fail(function () {
                alert("error");
            })
            .always(function () {
                console.log("finished");
            });

        })

        });


    </script>
```

Hope helps.

Comment: Not working. Kindly check the changes that i have made

Answer (score 0):

in your movies.cshtml you can just use the partial view like , also no need of adding extra script to show the modal you can just set the data-target and data-toggle attribute in your button.

```
@section Styles{
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
This is movies.cshtml
<button class="btn btn-warning" id="btnactor" data-toggle="modal" data 
target="#exampleModalactor">Add Actor</button>
<!-- your modal from partial view will be rendered here.-->
@Html.RenderPartial("Addactor")
@section scripts{
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 }
```

since you're adding the partial view with some model properties like name , dob you can pass the model like @Html.RenderPartial("Addactor",Model.PartialViewModel) where your PartialViewModel contains the properties name bio etc.

Comment: First of all I am not using view modal. I have created a partial view for an action. From my master view I need to call the modal located in partial view using a button click

Answer (score 0):

in movies.cshtml add the line:

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Addactor.cshtml")
```

I dont know what is the path of Addactor.cshtml so just replace "~/Views/Shared/Addactor.cshtml" by the right path.